# Store .shp to MySQL database with QGIS

Tags: qgis-2, mysql-spatial

I'm using QGIS 2.10 (Pisa) and I can´t store spatial information on my MySQL database (.shp or geojson). In previous versions that was allowed.

It's not supported anymore or there are any plugins or solutions for this?

If it isn't possible with QGIS is there another way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

See here how to do it. In this vídeos I teach two ways to store SHP in MySQL using QGIS.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAneh2VRaPkfuqlyT3kaiQcnuFpdg8nTg

Comment: Please describe what is in your video in words, preferably to a level of detail that may enable the asker to get their answer without viewing it.  Links can be used to support answers but they should not be the answer.